# Running Mario's TPM emulator with TSS Test suit

Tags: emulation, tpm, trusted

I am trying to run Mario's TPM-emulator(https://github.com/PeterHuewe/tpm-emulator) with TrouSerS (TSS Test API) & TSS API Test Suite.
As of now I have ran the whole setup including trouser stack and test suite with IBM's emulator.
So far I have successfully compiled and installed it. The default self tests are also getting passed when I start tpmd.
But I am not sure what configuration or commands are required to configure it so that I could use it with TSS API test suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mario's TPM-emulator uses cmake build system. It doesn't require any specific configuration as such.
Just set CC & ARCH in your environment and make the following change, open CMakeLists.txt and comment the add_subdirectory(tpmpd_dev) line.

```
$mkdir build
$cd build
$cmake ../
```

Comment: export environment_settings
make  CC="${CC}" AR="${AR}"